# node.js - Is there a way to make a discord bot send random pictures pulled from a file? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm new to Coding and I wanted to make a discord bot, I have an idea of how to do it, but I can't figure out how to do what I want.
I was wondering if there is a way to add a bunch of photos a file and have the discord bot be able to pull a a random picture out of it to send it? As well as maybe on that pulls like 5 random ones and sends them?

I have no idea what to do, and I haven't found anything to help with it.

Currently I'm doing one where I have to add every image ID on its own and make really long lines of code for every command.

Any ideas???

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.rand = function() {
  return this[Math.floor((Math.random()*this.length))];
}

console.log(["a","b","c"].rand())
```

(new edit since my previous answer didn't seem to sit right with some people)

Comment: You shouldn't pollute the `Array` prototype.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Math.random()` to pick a random image out of an array of images.

```js
const imageArray = [...];
const randomImage = imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*imageArray.length)];
```